# How do I dynamically determine in Blazor that one button has a different shape?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

I have three buttons. It could be more or less (dynamic). Dependent on the rights you have.
When you have a big screen, the buttons are from left to right. When you use a tablet. You will see the buttons among each other.

default look:

[image]

tablet look:

[image]

I want to show the button at the top right with a curve at the top right. In this example, the last button would have a curve on a computer screen and the first button on a tablet.

How can I dynamically reshape the button? I was thinking of determining what position it is in.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav col-12 col-md-auto justify-content-left mb-md-0">

        <li class="ms-5 mb-5">
            <TileButton Title="invoices"
                     Image="whiteSymbol.svg"
                     ImageHover="blueSymbol.svg"
                     Url="/myWebsite/invoices/"
                     OnClick=@DoAction />
        </li>

        <li class="ms-5 mb-5">
            <TileButton Title="orders"
                     Image="whiteSymbol.svg"
                     ImageHover="blueSymbol.svg"
                     Url="/myWebsite/orders"
                     OnClick=@DoAction />
        </li>

        <li class="ms-5 mb-5">
            <TileButton Title="purchase orders"
                     Image="whiteSymbol.svg"
                     ImageHover="blueSymbol.svg"
                     Url="/myWebsite/purchaseOrders"
                     OnClick=@DoAction />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    [Inject]
    private NavigationManager _navigationManager { get; set; }
    private void DoAction(string path) => _navigationManager.NavigateTo(path);
}
```

In the css:

```
.tilebutton {
    color: var(--mycolor);
    background-color: var(--mybackground);
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    width: 225px;
    height: 225px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.tilecontainer {
    width: 805px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is likely something that should be done with CSS. Using an `@media` query should accomplish what you want easily.

Comment: default blazor Template brings [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/browsers-devices/) , for CSS give it a try.

Comment: I was thinking about @media too. I use it for other things too. I will looking to the template.

Comment: Is it possible use a constant int in css. By example 1 for: if we have the first button then we need a rounding at the end? Or the constant value is 4, then we the fourth button gets a rounding end?

Comment: You'll have to show an example of how you want it to look, exactly.  Your verbal description isn't clear enough.  I'm assuming you mean that the top-right corner will always be rounded, no matter which button it happens to be.  If so, that's easy-- put the border radius on the parent container rather than any particular button.

Comment: I have changed the css-classes. The most right button exactly reach the top-right position of the container. But the rounding? I don't see him...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css I added the **z-index**, which component is showing first.

```
.tilebutton {
    color: var(--mycolor);
    background-color: var(--mybackground);
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    width: 225px;
    height: 225px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    z-index: auto !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.tilecontainer {
    width: 805px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 1 !important;
    border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

And in the container the "menu-items" (where the buttons are showing).

I added **overflow-hidden**. That was the answer where I was looking for.

```
<div class="container tilecontainer overflow-hidden">
   /* the three buttons */
</div>
```